# Dynamic file names to exported files in google SDK

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, export, command-line-interface, naming

i am trying to use Google's cloud command line interface (SDK) on desktop to extract a file from Google big query and place it in a google storage area. I have managed to do this initial part but now i want to give the file a dynamic date name as this process will be repeated in order to create a history of these files. The idea would be to have (filename).20.01.2020 or something like that so that we could have an organised history of these exports.

Here is what i currently have

```
bq extract mp-uid-all-touchpoints:83778322.prod_placementTouchpoints gs://touchpointsrecord/placements/%date%
```

What this does is correctly gather the current date and try to pass that as the filename. The problem is that in google sdk's syntax, '/' stands for newline, so when the date is passed in this format 'dd/mm/yyy' what ends up happening is it creates a new folder for day, month and then year.

i need it to just be one file not multiple folders within folders
hope someone can help solve

Answer (score 1):

Putting `/` will produce directory structure so becomes difficult to Read/Write objects with `/` in the name.
I suggest to try some other date format like `DDMMYYYY` or `DD-MM-YYYY` or `DD.MM.YYYY`

For `20012020`

```
export CURR_DATE=$(date '+%d%m%Y')
bq extract mp-uid-all-touchpoints:83778322.prod_placementTouchpoints gs://touchpointsrecord/placements/$CURR_DATE
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this format to create a file.

> gs://touchpointsrecord/placements-21-01-2020/

```
   gs://touchpointsrecord/placements-$(date '+%d-%m-%Y')
```